# three.js / envmap / renderToTexture / single texture

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping, render-to-texture

I'm creating an animation using envmap. 
Everything works as expected but instead of using 6 images inside a CubeTexture, I would like to use 6 animated textures.

I thought it would be obvious but I'm on it for hours now, I searched a lot everywhere I could but it's like nobody on earth ever used an animated texture as envMap...

I found some interesting posts concerning SphericalMappingReflection based on a single texture - exactly what I am looking for I think - , but impossible to find any example of use...

I also checked the Three.js shader source code in order to understand how envMap is done and I found theses lines

```
 #elseENVMAP_TYPE_EQUIREC
     float flipNormal = 1.0;
     #endif

     #ifdef ENVMAP_TYPE_CUBE
     vec4 envColor = textureCube( envMap, flipNormal * vec3( flipEnvMap * reflectVec.x, reflectVec.yz ) );

     #elif defined(  )
     vec2 sampleUV;
     sampleUV.y = saturate( flipNormal * reflectVec.y * 0.5 + 0.5 );
     sampleUV.x = atan( flipNormal * reflectVec.z, flipNormal * reflectVec.x ) * RECIPROCAL_PI2 + 0.5;
     vec4 envColor = texture2D( envMap, sampleUV );

     #elif defined( ENVMAP_TYPE_SPHERE )
     vec3 reflectView = flipNormal * normalize((viewMatrix * vec4( reflectVec, 0.0 )).xyz + vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0));
     vec4 envColor = texture2D( envMap, reflectView.xy * 0.5 + 0.5 );
     #endif
```

Then it looks possible to create an envMap using texture2D instead of textureCube, but I didn't find any hint on how to define "ENVMAP_TYPE_EQUIREC" or "ENVMAP_TYPE_SPHERE"

Can you help me please ? 
I feel a bit depressed with my problem and really don't know how to do.

Thank you !

( please excuse me if my english is not perfect, it's not my native language )

Comment: Well... 

It's really crasy because I'm looking for a solution since yesterday....

I wrote my question 10 minutes ago and I get it working just now :)

Here how to do it :


rttTexture.texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping

I thought I had tried this before, but I probably tried to set the mapping directly on the rttTexture instead of its property "texture"

Comment: Actually,
Even if it works, the result are not very good.
The quality is bad compared to a cubeTexture envmap 

Then if someone know how to put TextureObjects into a cubeTexture, I'm still interested.

Thanks

Comment: Well, I finally get it working !!! 

You need to create an additional Scene, put a Box in it with the RTT-Texture used a regular map with a CubeCamera at the center of the cube. And then use the CubeCamera.renderTarget.texture as envMap.

Unfortunately, it means that you need to render your texture 7 times (the first time, then once for each face of the cube) but it works